# Storing a Name for Your Project and Calling It in a Template

Tags: python, django

I've recently started a new Django project and was wondering where to store data like the name of my project/website/brand.

If my Django project was called "foo_bar" e.g., I wanna be able to save something like "FooBar" as my brand name somewhere and then use it in templates for titles etc.

What is the best practise for achieving that?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you save a variable in your "settings.py" file

```
name_project = "Foo_bar"


from django.conf import settings

class foo (view):
    def get(self, request):
        context = {
            name_project : settings.name_project
        }        
        return render(request, template_name, contexto)
```